# How ServiceLayer Facade should look like?

Tags: c#, .net, service, layer, facade

I have a simple N-Layer architechture: Presentation -> Service Layer -> Business Objects Layer - Data Access Layer. Service layer contain some Data provider services. I want to create facade for that layer.
Have no idea how it should look. I think it should contain CRUD-operations, but dont know how exactly? Need some examples.

I can create some CRUD operations, like "CreateCustomer() / CreateOrder()" and others , but what if entityes a lot? This approach will not work.

Pls, give me some examples of right facade of service layer

Answer (score 0):

You should have,

1. A Facade service for dependant entities like, a banking system comprises of Account, Employee etc. To create a bank you need to create its employee and accounts both. So, employee and account entities will be managed by two different services like EmployeeService and AccountService. Over that, you need to create BankService which will have EmployeeService and AccountService injected with. This will work as a Facade

   ```
   EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {

     createEmployee(Employee e) {}
     deleteEmployee(int empId) {}
     //
    }
   AccountServiceImpl implements AccountService {

     createAccount(Account e) {}
     deleteAccount(int empId) {}
     //
   }
   BankingServiceImpl implements BankingService {
     EmployeeService employeeService;
     AccountService accountService;

     createBank(Bank b) {
       Account a = b.getAccount();
       accountService.createAccount(a);

       Employee e = b.getEmployee();
       employeeService.createEmployee(e);
    }
   }
   ```
2. A factory pattern over your Facade. Each service will have a unique ID.

   ```
   ServiceFactory {
      public static Service getService(String id) {
           if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("Bank"))
               return new BankingServiceImpl();
           else if (id.equalsIgnoreCase("Account"))
               return new AccountServiceImpl();
           //
      } 
   }
   ```

something like that...

Comment: 1. You mean, like this CustomerService:ICRUD? 2. For what? why need an ID?

Answer (score 0):

Service layer is in fact a facade to infrastructure layer in your application 
it coordinate all activities among other infrastructure component ;
Well you can name operation with crude, like create, edit, delete, 
But as best practice you better name them with DDD principle; like create account 
Delete account , etc..
your service layer should have references to your infrastructure layer where repositories live and then use them in order to access your domain model ;

I hope this help.